# Local disk resources not working when connecting with remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I want to transfer files to a server using remote desktop local resources features. For some reason local disks are not shown in explorer on remote server even though I checked "disks" on Remote desktop local resources config tab. On remote server explorer I can see two broken icons in "Other" section with type "System folder" but when I click those icons nothing happens.

I Checked also remote server's Terminal services configuration and local resouces linking are allowed for TS sessions. So what's wrong here?

Comment: Check the version of the client you are using.

Comment: Connecting to the same server right? And if you log on to your system as another user?

Answer (score 4):

The only really reliable way to copy files over RDP that I have relied on, *almost* every time is using the \tsclient\c (or whatever drive you want) method. It does not work in a CMD window, but it works in an explorer window. To use it in a CMD session or script, launch it inside FAR manager or something similar.

It is convenient to use it like this:

```
start>run
\\tsclient\c
```

and a window with the local machines files will open.

Comment: +1, my drives were not available in explorer, but your command worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You say "local resouces linking are allowed for TS sessions". Just to check, you do mean in Terminal Services Configuration, in the RDP-Tcp connection properties, on the "Client Settings" tab the "Drive mapping" tick box is unticked?

JR

Comment: This works for my colleague so RDP-Tcp connection properties should be ok, this problem is somehow related to my laptop/account or something like that.

Comment: Get you colleague to TS from your laptop. If the drives don't connect it's your laptop, if they do it's your account. It's possible to disable drive connection in the Active Directory user properties (on the Environment tab of the user properties).

Answer (score 0):

What OS's are the client / server machines?

One thing to think about, although I am not sure if it affects it or not, is does the account you log into your terminal server session, have access to the local disks on the client machine? I am sure a year or two ago that was an issue for us.

Also this can bork when the machines are on different networks??

Comment: Client is Windows XP and server is windows server 2003. This works for my colleague who also has windows xp and is in same network so it must be somehow related to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but... Run a disk check on your laptop. I've seen some odd behavior occur when there are file system errors, even if they don't otherwise make themselves obvious. It should only take a few minutes to run and certainly won't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

When I connect from my work machines which runs XP to my home machine that runs Vista 64, my local folder opens and immediately closes.  If I open it again, it works fine.  This happens every time.  I don't know if you have a similar quirk, but I thought I throw it out there.